# Avoiding stale state in dynamically created functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form (`ItemsForm`) that needs to contain n copies of a subform (`Item`).
Currently I am maintaining an array of Items using the useState hook and it works fine.

The problem is that the parent form also has a state (`type`) which affects how `Item` is rendered (conditional fields depending on `type`). Whenever a new `Item` is added to state it keeps the stale value of type at the time of creation and is no longer aware of updates.

Below is a very simplified example just to illustrate. The goal is that when `type` changes in the parent form then this change should be reflected in the `Item` components. Fields inside each Item also needs to maintain anything a user might have typed in.

```
const ItemsForm = ({type}) => {

  const Item = ({type}) => {
    return <div>
      Type is: {type}<br />
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
  }

  const [items, setItems] = useState([React.createElement(Item, {type}, null)])

  const handleAdd = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setItems([...items, React.createElement(Item, {type}, null)])
  }

  return <form>
    {items}
    <button type="button" onClick={handleAdd}>
      Add new item
    </Button>
  </form>
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing the `Item` array in the state? Why not just re-render each component?

Comment: Because when re-rendering the component anything a user has entered gets lost. I've just updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put React elements into state. Generally, state is easiest to manage when it's composed solely of JSON-serializable values: primitives, possibly nested inside of objects and arrays.

In this case, the only real stateful thing in ItemsForm appears to be the number of copies, so use that for state:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [type, setType] = React.useState('');
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={type} onChange={e => setType(e.target.value)} />
      <ItemsForm type={type} />
    </div>
  );
}; 
const Item = ({type}) => {
  return <p>Type is: {type}</p>
}
const ItemsForm = ({type}) => {
  const [itemCount, setItemCount] = React.useState(1);

  const handleAdd = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setItemCount(itemCount + 1);
  }

  return <form>
    {Array.from({ length: itemCount }, () => <Item type={type} />)}
    <button type="button" onClick={handleAdd}>
      Add new item
    </button>
  </form>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

> The goal is that when type changes in the parent form then this change should be reflected in the Item components.

Render new elements by mapping the JSX when returning from the component (*not when setting the state anew*), and then it's a simple matter of passing those JSX elements the possibly-changed prop.

Demo with both a label and inputs for the copied component:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [type, setType] = React.useState('');
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={type} onChange={e => setType(e.target.value)} />
      <ItemsForm type={type} />
    </div>
  );
}; 
const Item = ({type}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
  return <div>
    <p>Type is: {type}</p>
    <input value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
  </div>;
}
const ItemsForm = ({type}) => {
  const [itemCount, setItemCount] = React.useState(1);

  const handleAdd = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setItemCount(itemCount + 1);
  }

  return <form>
    {Array.from({ length: itemCount }, (_, i) => <Item key={i} type={type} />)}
    <button type="button" onClick={handleAdd}>
      Add new item
    </button>
  </form>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: This was actually the first approach I tried, but quickly realised that since it re-renders all the Items whenever you add/remove Items it also wipes all the form fields inside each Item

Comment: The "copied" components should each have their own state, then, eg: `const MyForm = ({ type }) => { const [value, setValue] = useState(''); return <form><input value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} /> ...`

Comment: I'm presuming you mean still following the approach in your answer, using a loop. It sounds to me like the items' local states would still be destroyed because they are being rendered in a loop. But maybe I'm wrong. Would you be able to update your answer to show how you mean?

Comment: The fact that the components are rendered in a loop shouldn't be any issue, see snippet

Comment: I think the reason this approach didn't work for me originally was that I declared Item inside ItemsForm. Not clear on why, but some scoping issue causing the subform to re-render when adding new ones.